# Django's template language can not safely process dict

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In django's template language, if a variable called `a.x`, then django will try in this order to get the right value：

1. `a['x']`, dictionary lookup
2. `a.x` or `a.x()`, attribute or method lookup
3. `a[x]`, list indexing

The result is: any variable that support `var['str']` becomes a time bomb. Imagine `a` is a `dict`, with a key 'items' whoes value is 'hello world', then `a.items` will result in 'hello world', not `ditc.items()`. Here is the code:

```
from django.template import Engine, Context
template = """
{% for k, v in a.items %}
{{ k }} = {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
"""

e = Engine()
t = e.from_string(template)
a = {'items': 'hello world'}
print(t.render(Context({'a': a})))
```

While I expect `items = hello world` as the output, the real output is:

```
h = 

e = 

l = 
...
```

For a dict variable, if it has a key with the same name of a dict method, then you will never be able to call that method in the template. It becomes a time bomb because you never know if in the future you will add a key called 'items' into a dict variable.

Such risk is not only for dict but any type which accept `var['key']`.

So my question is, why the order is designed like this, and how to make it safe.

Comment: Your expected output should be `items = hello world`, not `a = ...`

Comment: @DeepSpace You're right, corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple workaround (besides using a better name for your keys):

```
from django.template import Engine, Context

template = """
{% for k, v in items_func %}
{{ k }} = {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
"""

e = Engine()
t = e.from_string(template)
a = {'items': 'hello world'}
print(t.render(Context({'a': a, 'items_func': a.items})))
>> items = hello world
```

Answer (score 2):

> why the order is designed like this

It's designed like this because the template syntax is supposed to be simple and doing so encourages you to put more logic into the view rather than in the template.

> How to make it safe?

*Give your keys a descriptive name*

"items" doesn't do anything to actually describe what should be inside of the key, so not only will it give django a headache, it will give any other developer that has to debug an issue with this dictionary a headache too.

Answer (score 2):

By using the `.` for three different lookups, there's always the potential for a problem like this. If the order was changed to try `a.x` first, then it would cause problems for other users that wanted to access `a['x']`.

I don't think there's a general way to protect against this behaviour. Once you're burned by it once, you'll remember not to put an `items` key in your dictionaries in future.

As a last resort, you could switch to Jinja, which supports subscript syntax, `{{ foo['bar'] }}`. That means that `{{ foo.bar }}` checks for the attribute `foo.bar` first. See the [Jinja docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#variables) for more information.